# Can I develop an app with the Lollipop SDK for a 4.3 or 4.4 phone?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.4-kitkat, android-5.0-lollipop

I recently received an invite to use Inbox and it is using the new material design feature from 5.0. So this got me wondering if I can develop an app with the new SDK to enable BLE peripheral, but for a Jellybean or KitKat device. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Here is the list of updates: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2014/10/whats-new-in-android-50-lollipop.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

There are support libraries released to help backport apps running on older versions of Android. [Here's a list of all of the support libraries and what they allow you to do](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Perihiperal profile has only just been introduced, but hasn't made it's way in to the support libraries. My guess would be because it's rooted much further down in the OS and isn't something that an app can bring in. This suggests that it won't ever be possible (unless perhaps the user is running a custom ROM).

4.3+ already supports lots of Bluetooth LE features, it just doesn't support peripheral profiles. I have personally been waiting for this for a project of mine, so very excited that it's now available in Lollipop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's a lot clearer now what is supported.